# Compiling boost with MSVC2015 with /std:c++latest (or C++17/N4190)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, c++17

When I try to build boost with MSVC2015 with the `/std:c++latest` flag I get an error:

```
boost\algorithm\string\detail\case_conv.hpp(33): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
```

Which points to:

```
 // a tolower functor
 template<typename CharT>
 struct to_lowerF : public std::unary_function<CharT, CharT>
```

Now this seems to be due to N4190 as mentioned here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs

> /std:c++latest also controls the removal of the following old
>   features: N4190 "Removing auto_ptr, random_shuffle(), And Old Stuff",
>   P0004R1 "Removing Deprecated Iostreams Aliases", LWG 2385
>   "function::assign allocator argument doesn't make sense", and various
>   non-Standard features (the std::tr1 namespace, some TR1-only
>   machinery, and the std::identity struct).

When using:

```
 std::string a,b;
 return boost::iequals(a,b);
```

And using `boost::ilexicographical_compare`.

Its also mentioned here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/06/19/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rtm/

> ```
> Stephan T. Lavavej - MSFT
>
> Azarien: Removing auto_ptr/etc. will have positive consequences. It will prevent new code from using outdated/complicated/unsafe
> ```
>
> machinery, and it will reduce confusion among non-expert users. **(For
>   example, unnecessary unary_function/binary_function inheritance is
>   common**, because many users thought that STL algorithms/containers
>   required this, when in fact only the outdated adapters did.) And
>   auto_ptr in particular is unsafe, because its mutating "copy"
>   constructor silently moves from lvalues.

So how do I get boost to compile with VC2015's /std:c++latest? Right now it appears boost isn't C++17 compatible?

Comment: Report the issue.. http://www.boost.org/development/bugs.html .. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/newticket

Answer (score 9):

Define the macro `_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC` before including **any** headers. For your own code, if you're using Visual Studio's build system, this is best accomplished by way of your project's [Preprocessor Definitions setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions). For building Boost itself, add `define=_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC` to your `b2`/`bjam` invocation.

Other previously-standard functionality implicitly disabled by `/std:c++latest` can be controlled by defining the macros `_HAS_FUNCTION_ASSIGN`, `_HAS_OLD_IOSTREAMS_MEMBERS`, and `_HAS_TR1_NAMESPACE`. These macros are all outlined in the following blog articles:

[STL Fixes In VS 2015 Update 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/08/12/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-update-3/)
[VS 2015 Update 2’s STL is C++17-so-far Feature Complete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/01/22/vs-2015-update-2s-stl-is-c17-so-far-feature-complete/)